# Help in migrating from ISAPI_Rewrite to IIS7 URL Rewriting

Tags: regex, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I've this ISAPI_Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule /([^/.?]+) /sc.asp?p=$1 [I,L]
```

This rule should rewrite Urls like:

> /some-article
>
> /article2

and **shouldn't** rewrite Urls like:

> /home.asp
>
> /admin (because there's a directory named admin)
>
> /admin/
>
> /sites/gutterman

It works great in ISAPI_Rewrite
Yesterday I bought a Windows 2008 R2 VPS, and I started to transfer my ASP-classic web application to the new server. Now, everything is working great, except for URL Rewriting. I google-ed a little bit and found that the IIS7 URL Rewrite module is completely different from the ISAPI_Rewrite.

I created a **Blank Rule**. In the pattern I set `/([^/.?]+)`, in Action -> Action Type I set `Rewrite` and in Action -> Action properties -> Rewrite Url I set `sc.asp?p={R:0}`. It didn't work.

After some googling I found that I have to remote the `/` character in the start of my pattern (so my pattern is now `([^/.?]+)`). So I did it, and now, it is just rewriting *any* url, and it should rewrite only urls that aren't directories or files.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to avoid rewriting URLs that actually point to existing files is to add these conditions:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
```

Also, your match pattern shows a common misconception. The querystring is not passed to the Match URL pattern, so you don't need to look for `?`.